# Realm работа со временем

Tags: android, база-данных, realm, realm-database

Допустим я напишу запрос: получить данные которые изменялись 5 минут назад(одно из полей - время последнего обновления). Так как время идет, постепенно все больше объектов будут удовлетворять данному фильтру. Будет ли `Realm` оповещать об этом или мне самому надо периодически это проверять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Realm` оповещает только если к-л поле объекта из уже имеющейся выборки изменилось или был добавлен/удалён объект выборки.

Т.к. с течением времени никакие поля в объектах сами по себе не меняются, то выборки по, например, полю с датой обновляться автоматом не будут, т.к. в БД ничего не изменилось. Т.е. да - надо постоянно вручную перезапрашивать выборку